# Android - Change Library from Gradle Behaviour?

Tags: android, gradle

If I include a library via gradle for an android project, can I change the source code of said library (for instance to force a specific typeface) and have that code not get modified each time the code gets update?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of ways to consider going about this:

1. You should be able to download the specific version of the library you need and place it in the `libs` directory, edit the code you need to change, then in your `build.gradle` make sure that you have the following:

   dependencies {
       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
   }

   This will prevent gradle from pulling the latest version of the library from its repository. You will have to manually update in the future if you want to go this route.
2. If the methods you need to change are not private, you can create a child class and perform method overriding to suit your needs.